# To maximize the polynomial using Genetic Algorithm

Tags: genetic-algorithm

How to maximize below polynomial using Genetic Algorithm
`F(X) = X3 -97X2 +2700X+200`
When `X` is non-negative integer and is less than or equal to `31`

Comment: What are you asking for? Do you need to know what a Genetic Algorithm is or how it works? Or how to implement it? Or something else?

Comment: No,only just I need the solution of the above.If you can then pleas provide me the code either in java/cpp.

Answer (score 0):

For a polynomial like this, it might be better to compute the derivative of `F(x)`, i.e. `F'` and use `F'` to figure out the monotonic regions of `F` (i.e. regions in which `F(x)` is either monotonically increasing or decreasing`.

Then you can pick the nearest integers to the boundaries of monotonic regions, and limit your search to those few.

Using a genetic algorithm is not likely to be effective here, because the gene is just one number. If you mutate the gene, you are basically doing local search and switching numbers, which could be much less effective than looking at the slopes/gradients.

Comment: With such a small search space (32 numbers) I wouldn't even bother to implement the derivative.  Just loop through the possiblee values of `X` and see which gives the largest value.

Comment: @Degustaf. You are right. For such a small search space, a brute force search will do for any optimization problem.